# Why haven't I earned "enlightened" for this question?

Tags: support, badges, enlightened-badge

My answer has a score of 10 and is accepted...

[How do I use regular javascript to look through every <a> tag and change the href?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219431/how-do-i-use-regular-javascript-to-look-through-every-a-tag-and-change-the-href/2219444#2219444)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mouse over the timestamps, and you'll see Andrew Moore's answer came in 33 seconds before yours.  That disqualifies you for the Enlightened badge on that question.

Comment: I see. I thought "first" meant the first time I got ten upvotes and the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely Andrew Moore's or F.Aquino's answer was posted before yours. Enlightened requires that your answer is the **first** answer to the question.